How to estimate a feasible Generalized Error-in-Variable Model (combine deming regression/TLS and f-generalized least squares)
I have observational data with spatial structure.  A hypothetical dataset could be brain mass for 100 species of birds and body mass for those same species.  The data has spatial structure because they coevolved through time along the paths of an evolutionary tree making the error more similar for more closely related species.  There is often also significant white noise independent of the spatial structure.
Because this is observational data I'd like to account for errors in both traits, and allow the possibility that these two errors have different spatial structures.  Even though the underlying spatial structure is the same, one trait could have it's error predominantly from white noise while the other trait's error has little white noise.
However, I am having trouble developing an error-in-variable deming-styled regression.  My question is this.  I already know I have to specify either the explicit variances of the two errors or at least their ratio, but do I also I need to specify the relative amount of white noise?  If my spatial structure is described by $\Sigma$ and my white noise by $I_{n}$ (where I is n x n identity matrix) so that my total error variance for trait one is $\sigma_{1a}^{2}\Sigma+\sigma_{1b}^{2}I$ and is $\sigma_{2a}^{2}\Sigma+\sigma_{2b}^{2}I$ for trait 2, can I get away with only specifying the ratio $(\sigma_{1a}^{2}+\sigma_{1b}^{2})/(\sigma_{2a}^{2}+\sigma_{2b}^{2})$ and then fit $\sigma_{1a}^{2}$, $\sigma_{1b}^{2}$, $\sigma_{2a}^{2}$, $\sigma_{2b}^{2}$ with a technique like feasible generalized least squares (or some other technique)?  Or is it necessary to also specify these variance modifiers in order to successfully fit an error-in-variable regression model to my observational data with potentially different spatial structures of the errors?
If it helps, I am more than happy to log-transform the data first (as there is great biological motivation for doing so, and I understand log(error) may behave much better than untransformed error.
